# how to detect boxes in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, gridview, layout

I am having many different 6By6 matrices. Each matrix contains different values. Those values represent how the layout will be divided. 
Each matrix should have consistent rectangles as follows (There should be continous rectangles, the colors represent the separate consistent rectangles):
[image: a matrix shown by plt.imshow]

So my problem, is how to detect successfully those boxes (rectangles).
I want as output a list of arrays. Each array should refer to ith index, the j th index and the value of that rectangles.

For example, I have as input this matrix [[35. 11. 11. 11. 11.  0.],[10. 10. 10. 10. 10.  0.],[ 10. 10. 10. 10. 10.  0.],[
 34. 34. 34. 34. 34.  0.],[ 34. 34. 34. 34. 34.  0.],[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

So I want as output [[0,0,35],[0,4,11],[1,4,10],[2,4,10],[3,4,34],[4,4,34],[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[5,5,0]]

My trial for detecting the rectangles is in this code:

```
#Detect the rectangles in the matrices
def detect_rectangle(T):
i = 0
j = 0
elem = T[0,0]
rectanglesList = []
n,m = T.shape
while (i < n) and (j<m):
    #print('i,j, elem',i,j,elem)      
    if (i == n-1 and j == m-1): # if we reached the end of the matrix
        rectanglesList.append([i,j,elem])
        break;
    if (j == m-1): #in case we reached the end of columns, we reeinitialize the columns
        if (i != n -1):
            i += 1
            elem = T[i,j]
        else:
            rectanglesList.append([i,j,T[i,j]])
            j = 0
            break;
    elif T[i,j] == T[i,j+1]: #in case the element in the next column is equal, continue and check further, store it as elem
        j +=1
        elem = T[i,j]
    elif T[i,j] != T[i,j+1] :
        rectanglesList.append([i,j,T[i,j]])
        j += 1
        elem = T[i,j]
    if (i == n-1): #in case we reached the end of rows
        if j != n -1 :
            j += 1
            elem = T[i,j]
        else:
            rectanglesList.append([i,j,elem])
            i = 0
            break
    else:
        if (T[i,j] == T[i+1,j]) and (elem == T[i,j]): #in case the element in the next row is equal
            i += 1
        elif (T[i,j] == T[i+1,j]) and (elem != T[i,j]): #in case the element in the next row is equal
            elem = T[i,j]
            i+= 1
        elif ((T[i,j] != T[i+1,j] and elem == T[i,j])): #in case it is not equal to neither the element in the next row nor the element in the next column
            rectanglesList.append([i,j,elem])
            #j +=1
            elem = T[i,j]
        elif T[i,j] != T[i+1,j] :
            i += 1
            elem = T[i,j]


return rectanglesList
```

So the code that I wrote is detecting the rectangles but in more separate way. I always have as output arrays that refer to a value that has just one row and one column as indexes.

Comment: What triangles are you talking about? And can elaborate more on how your output is related to your input? It is hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: it's a typing mistake. I meant rectangles not triangles. I will correct it. sorry for the incovenience

Comment: Can you please explain, how your output is related to your input in your example? Does your code work or are there errors?

Comment: @Merlin1896 So as input I have a matrix. This matrix contains different values. I want to extract from this matrix the rows or the rectangles or the part that has one value. So I want a script that goes through the matrix extract all the rows that has similar values. For example, I want as output a list of these kind of arrays. array1 = [0,4,5] and array2=[1,3,20]. The first element in array1 which is 0 refer to this position (row 0 and column 4). it means that in row 0, from column 0 until column 4 I have value 5. Is that a bit clearer ?

Comment: My code works but the output that I am getting doesn't match with the output that I want to have.

Comment: And how would you represent a block that sits in the middle of a row? So for example you have a 6 by 6 matrix where the first three rows look like this `[1,1,1,1,1,1],[10,10,2,2,2,12],[1,1,1,1,1,1]` What is the expected output?

Comment: in that case, I expect as output this list of arrays ([0,5,1],[1,1,10],[1,4,2],[1,5,12],[2,5,1]). If I have a block in the middle , then I would interpret my output this way: in row 1 from column 0 to column 1 I have the value 1, then in the same row 1 from column 1 until column 4 I have the value 2 then from column 4 to column 5 I have the value 12.

Comment: In your initial example in the question, you mention the following two lists as part of your desired output: `[0,0,0],[1,0,0]` Where do these entries come from?

Comment: I wanted to refer to the value 0 that was placed vertically in the column 5 but I couldn't represent it the right way. So we can skip those arrays for now. I meant we can now just take care of detectin the blocks horizontally, you can consider [0,0,0] and [1,0,0] as mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
x=np.array([[35,11,11,11,11,0],[10,10,10,10,10,0],
            [10,10,10,10,10,0],[34,34,34,34,34,0],
            [34,34,34,34,34,0], [0,0,12,12,12,0]])
outputs=[]
for i, row in enumerate(x):
    last_ele=row[0]
    for j, val in enumerate(row[1:]):
        if val == last_ele:
            continue
        outputs.append([i,j, last_ele])
        last_ele=val
    outputs.append([i,len(row)-1, last_ele])
print(outputs)

# [[0, 0, 35], [0, 4, 11], [0, 5, 0], [1, 4, 10], 
#  [1, 5, 0], [2, 4, 10], [2, 5, 0], [3, 4, 34], 
#  [3, 5, 0], [4, 4, 34], [4, 5, 0], [5, 1, 0],
#  [5, 4, 12], [5, 5, 0]]
```

We simply iterate once over the rows and and check if the preceding element is the same as the current. If it is not, then we add the last seen element to our output list along with the row and column index.

Comment: hats off ! Thank you :)